# How do you spell wifi / Wi-Fi / WiFi?

Tags: orthography, capitalization, abbreviations, hyphenation, open-vs-closed-vs-hyphenated

This is probably related to whether one should capitalize Internet or not. I am looking for the correct spelling of wifi when referring to a wireless connection to the Internet. I want to tell the users of my iPhone app that they cannot use their cellular network to watch the HD videos.

If I use the capitalized and hyphenated version as seen on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi), will I be referring to the Wi-Fi brand rather than the concept of wifi?

> "Wi-Fi" is a trademark of the Wi-Fi Alliance and the brand name for
>   products using the IEEE 802.11 family of standards.

Some dude on [Meta.stackoverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104247/rename-wifi-to-wi-fi) made this claim with no explanation:

> WiFi" is a bit better than "wifi" as it asserts the etymology, compare
>   history of usage of "hifi" from which it derives. – Steve-o Aug 29 at
>   3:59

Comment: The Wi-Fi Alliance is just a trade association. They won't come knocking on your door in the middle of the night if you use their terminology. They're only interested in shutting out comptetition from any major global manufacturers who don't want to join them. Anyway, you've answered your own question by the mere fact that you happily wrote **wifi** twice in the first paragraph before wondering about capitalisation/hyphenation. Use what comes naturally to mind.

Comment: My experience (non-native speaker from Europe) is: "WiFi" is rarely used, most people/places refer to it as "WLAN". I'm curous: does anyone else observe this outside of the US? In German language text I see "WLAN" being used exclusively and in English language text around Europe there seems to be a strong tendency towards "WLAN".

Comment: @Joachim: WLAN is uncommon in Swedish (which is a Germanic language). I suspect the Nordic languages borrow more frequently from English than the ones further south. We also don't dub movies. :)

Comment: This reminds me very much of this question: **[Is “blah blah blah” the most common spelling?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/79439/is-blah-blah-blah-the-most-common-spelling)**

Comment: @Mari-LouA Maybe the question should be edited to remove the iPhone remark, thus making it "less localized"?

Comment: @landroni I don't think that's the problem, the question is asking which written form is preferable when speaking about wireless connection in order to avoid trademark issues.

Comment: @Matthew: This was nearly 3 years ago, and I honestly can't remember for certain, but I think it's unlikely I personally specified "Too Localised" (which is no longer available). I probably said it was "Not Constructive" (also no longer available), which would be in line with the comment I made at the time. And it just so happened TL was cited more often by the other 4 closevoters. IMHO the question is utterly pointless, because no-one is "in charge" of defining correct usage here, and the idea of the Wi-Fi Alliance "owning" that particular representation is frankly risible.

Comment: (To which I would also add that I've always had a lot of respect for [Neil Coffey's comments](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/41180/how-do-you-spell-wifi-wi-fi-wifi?noredirect=1#comment75662_41183), including this one here.)

Comment: If you check the Wi-Fi alliance website you'll notice they use *Wi-Fi*. I don't always write it like that but I would say that is the more "correct" way of doing it. Some people do refer to it as WLAN, namely in Austria/Germany, but WLAN stands for Wireless LAN and can be used to refer to other technologies. [HiperLAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HiperLAN) is another example of a WLAN.

Comment: @JoachimSauer: I very rarely hear or read people using "WLAN" in place of WiFi/Wi-Fi/wifi/Wifi in the United States (and I'm a programmer, so I read about such things often).  I suspect it is a convention limited to certain regions of the world.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you have an iPhone app and it would seem that Apple/iPhone use the term "Wi-Fi" throughout then I would use the same for consistency. iPhone users expect to see "Wi-Fi".

However, there could be a regional difference...

> Note: iOS devices sold in China may use the term Wireless LAN (WLAN)
>   instead of Wi-Fi.

Reference: http://support.apple.com/kb/ts1398

(**EDIT:** For comparison, my Nokia E65 (sold in the UK) uses the terms "WLAN" or "Wireless LAN" exclusively, no mention of "Wi-Fi" or its derivatives.)

Answer (score 14):

In the past it was "Wi-Fi", but the current trend is toward "wifi".

It's a little like e-Mail => eMail => email.

**December 2015 update:** A Google search now results in 41% more occurences of "wi-fi" than "wifi". Apparently the trend has reversed.

Comment: Could you provide some kind of reference to back up this claim please?

Comment: This question was closed, inappropriately in my opinion, because it is "unlikely to help any future visitors." But you can Google "wi-fi" and "wifi", and you'll find that wifi has more hits. "Wi-fi" used to have more hits.

Comment: I believe this question should be reopened. Can we say two years later that this trend been confirmed?

Comment: Even 4 years later with 27,000 views, this question is still "unlikely to help any future visitors".

Comment: I've never seen e-Mail (with capital 'M') being common (or eMail either for that matter), and I don't remember it being the original.  I'm sure I've seen it (or them) here and there, but chalked it up to people who are not a part of mainstream tech culture, a little bit like people who spell *OS X* as *OSX* or *iOS* as *Ios*  Do you have any evidence that that was the original?  My memory is that "e-mail" was the original (and it is the convention I still adhere to).

Comment: Google hit counts are not good evidence of this kind of spelling difference. Google routinely reinterprets words with punctuation without notification in the user interface. For example I just searched for "e-mail" with a hyphen and the first hit is for an article that has the word "email" without a hyphen.

Comment: "A Google search now results in 41% more occurences of "wi-fi" than "wifi"." - 2+ years on and this seems to be nearer 52% for me. However, I am a bit surprised at this difference. I would have expected Google to have treated "WiFi" as an _exact_ synonym of "Wi-Fi" (unless you are perhaps searching with a quoted phrase), yet the organic search results do appear to have significant differences, even on the first page. (?)

Answer (score 11):

According to publications like [PC Magazine](http://www.pcmag.com/encyclopedia_term/0,2542,t=WiFi&i=54444,00.asp) which would be more likely to use the "correct" spelling, the word is spelled:

> **Wi-Fi**
>
> A wireless local area network (WLAN) technology that conforms to the IEEE 802.11 standard. Wi-Fi is the wireless counterpart to the wired Ethernet network, which is the ubiquitous local area network (LAN) technology used in companies and homes worldwide. A Wi-Fi logo from the Wi-Fi Alliance certifies that network devices comply with the IEEE 802.11 standards.

However, [WordNet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordNet) from Princeton spells it [**WiFi**](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=wifi). Based on a quick Google search, most official sites (such as Starbucks) use either WiFi or Wi-Fi. Since there is so much variation, *wifi* looks fine as it is, and people understand the forms *wifi*, *WiFi*, *Wi-Fi* and possibly *Wifi*, you could use any of them and still be fine. The key to your use is that you are aiming towards being understood, not necessarily maintaining the trademark. (If we all maintained trademarks, we wouldn't refer to *Blackberries* instead of *Blackberry mobile devices*.)

Comment: I really think this is one case where even in quotes, the word "correct" is a bit misplaced. Also note that even after many decades, usage for the analogous **hifi/hi-fi** is still split pretty much 50-50, so it ain't going anywhere fast.

Comment: I think all variations of wifi are understandable. I'm not worried about sounding strange to my users. I'm just wondering if a particular variant would result in legal issues because it refers to a company's trademark rather than a general concept.

Comment: Prepare yourself for the possibility that the freelance journalist writing for PC Magazine arbitrarily chose the orthography that they preferred and nobody cared terribly much. Whether that makes it "correct" or not I think is a largely pointless and/or unanswerable question...

Comment: It is highly unlikely that _PC Magazine_ left its style decision for _Wi-Fi_ to a freelance journalist who happened to be writing the entry for that topic in its "PC Encyclopedia"—especially since the piece was posted in the days when _PC Magazine_ still had (I believe) a copyediting staff. I know for a fact that _PC World_ (which for years was the biggest print rival of _PC Mag_) maintained a house word list that was several hundred pages long, and that _Wi-Fi_ appeared on that list only after considerable research and consultation with various in-house editors.

Answer (score 8):

The correct spelling is Wi-Fi even if wifi is most used.

Google Trends clearly shows this:
[image: wifi vs Wi-Fi on google trends]

If it's technical document, I would use Wi-Fi. But, if SEO is very important, I would use wifi (+other keywords to create a long tail keyword).

Valeria (anyway, on the [Tanaza](https://www.tanaza.com) website we use only Wi-Fi)

Comment: This may be the most _practical_ answer, but I suppose people on this site are not terribly concerned about practical matters, hence the fact that I'm the first to vote up.

Comment: Google search term frequencies are not necessarily a good indicator of what is most used. These track what people entered into the search box, and it is quite plausible that even people who prefer the term "Wi-Fi" tend to type the search term "wifi" just for convenience. Without making the distinction, you shouldn't assume that search term frequency is an accurate reflection of usage frequency.

Comment: "on the Tanaza website we use only Wi-Fi" - Although you seem to have switched over to mostly "WiFi" more recently? And (presumably in your attempt at SEO) on some pages you seem to randomly switch between "WiFi" and "Wi-Fi", which is rather inconsistent (and confusing) and portrays a less professional image to your readers in my opinion.

Answer (score 5):

According to [Google's Developer Documentation Style Guide](https://developers.google.com/style/word-list#wifi), it should be spelled `Wi-Fi`.

Answer (score 4):

**Wi-Fi** is a trademark of the Wi-Fi Alliance.  The name is sometimes written as **WiFi**, **Wifi**, or **wifi**, but these are **not** approved by the Wi-Fi Alliance. -- *[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi)*

This is a case similar to facial tissues being generically referred to as "Kleenex".  There are many examples of a trademark becoming a generic term, in which case the original capitalization or other unique stylization become lost or varied.  Other common examples include Aspirin, Cellophane, Dry ice, Escolator, Kerosene, Lanolin, Laundromat, Linoleum, TelePrompTer, Thermos, Trampoline, and Videotape. -- *[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_generic_and_genericized_trademarks)*

The official term is "Wi-Fi".  However, when English users treat a trademark generically, the "rules" for what is proper become the relative prevalence of the unofficial usage.

Comment: So theoretically in something like technical documentation which accompanied software, one would need to acknowledge that `"Wi-Fi" is a registered trademark of the Wi-Fi Alliance`.  We're going with "Wired" and "Wireless" [Network].

Answer (score 3):

FWIW, [Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Wi-Fi) came down on "Wi-Fi" -- so if you want to cite a source, there it is.

Comment: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Wi-Fi   Granted, it's not a very good definition.

Answer (score 1):

I'd just like to weigh in here. It would seem that Windows 10 prefers "WiFi" in British English and "Wi-Fi" in American English. I noticed this when I changed my display language. I've probably used both orthographies from time to time, but I think I prefer the hyphenated version.

Answer (score 1):

For modern practical style I almost always go with The Guardian, which has [wifi](https://www.theguardian.com/guardian-observer-style-guide-w).

Answer (score 1):

[Apple](https://help.apple.com/applestyleguide/?fbclid=IwAR0OlHl0mvq0Omz6rpKRVMoQ5675F8QkTqaR7MgqyofeRFUeX_Gnec9s2aU#/apsg48ccd3b3) and [Google](https://developers.google.com/style/word-list?hl=en#letter-w) style guides both still say Wi-Fi.

Apple: "Wi-Fi. Not wifi, wi-fi, or WiFi."

Google: "Wi-Fi; not wifi or WiFi. When possible, instead use wireless."

Comment: Are Apple and Google both members of the Wi-Fi Alliance? If so that would explain their choice of styling.

Answer (score 0):

We use Wi-Fi as the generic term but are keeping an eye on the prevailing usage as with many tech terms.

An often-overlooked aspect of spelling/hyphenating terms is implied pronunciation. In "Wi-Fi," it's natural to read each "i" as "eye," whereas "wifi" is a bit ambiguous and some might read it as "wiffy."

Comment: I'm sorry, but are '[w]e' the usage panel at OED, the board at IBM, or the local darts team?